# Mapping Aggregated Results in JDBi

Tags: jdbc, aggregate-functions, jdbi

Aggregation query is `select min(sal) as minSal, max(sal) maxSal from Emp`.

I think it is redundant to create a `Mapper` and `VO` only for this use-case.

Is there a predefined `mapper` where I can post result into a `map` for example exists in `JDBi`?

Comment: I've looked for a solution for this for a while but couldn't. Ended up implementing a generic mapper which returns Map<String, Object>

Comment: Yes I too ended up writing of my own

Answer (score 1):

There is the class [`DefaultMapper`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/DefaultMapper.html) available to do this.

```
package org.skife.jdbi.v2;

public class DefaultMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Map<String, Object>> {
  /* .... */
}
```